# Infinite authentication loop only in IE

Tags: asp.net-mvc, internet-explorer, authentication, identityserver3

#### Question / Issue

I have an infinite redirect loop that only occurs in Internet Explorer and not in Chrome or Firefox. This affects multiple developers across two applications (MVC 5  .NET 4.6 and MVC6 .NET Core). I'm using IdentityServer3 to authenticate using cookies. Everything progresses fine until I complete the login process. After the login process is complete I am authenticated and the control is returned to the .NET apps, but at that point the application doesn't seem to realize that I'm logged in in IE and begins the entire authentication loop all over again (and this is where it enters the infinite loop). In Chrome or Firefox I instead get sent to the redirect url and everything is authenticated as it should be.

While looking at the application insights log I get the output below ( I scrubbed out my client secrets and ids. All entries of those were identical before removal. I also scrubbed the identity server address which I called SCRUBBED.ADDRESS).

Any clues on how to get around this?

#### Relevant parts of the log file

## .NET Output (For IE)

```
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ChallengeResult:Information: Executing ChallengeResult with authentication schemes ().
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OpenIdConnect.OpenIdConnectMiddleware:Information: AuthenticationScheme: oidc was challenged.
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker:Information: Executed action OSPI.Framework.Core.Mvc.UI.Controllers.LandingPageController.Index (OSPI.Framework.Core.Mvc) in 23.2833ms
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost:Information: Request finished in 42.7694ms 302 
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost:Information: Request starting HTTP/1.1 POST http://localhost:44360/signin-oidc application/x-www-form-urlencoded 1655
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies.CookieAuthenticationMiddleware:Information: AuthenticationScheme: Cookies signed in.
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost:Information: Request finished in 760.7735ms 302 
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost:Information: Request starting HTTP/1.1 GET http://localhost:44360/  
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.DefaultAuthorizationService:Information: Authorization failed for user: (null).
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker:Information: Authorization failed for the request at filter 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Authorization.AuthorizeFilter'.
```

## Identity Server Output:

```
2017-06-05 08:22:55.492 -07:00 [Information] Start authorize request
2017-06-05 08:22:55.492 -07:00 [Information] Start authorize request protocol validation
2017-06-05 08:22:56.179 -07:00 [Information] "Authorize request validation success"
 "{
  \"ClientId\": \"\",
  \"ClientName\": \"Youth Re-engagement\",
  \"RedirectUri\": \"https://localhost/YouthReengagement/SelectOrganization\",
  \"AllowedRedirectUris\": [
    \"https://SCRUBBED.ADDRESS/YouthReengagement/SelectOrganization\",
    \"https://localhost/YouthReengagement/SelectOrganization\",
    \"http://localhost/YouthReengagement/SelectOrganization\"
  ],
  \"SubjectId\": \"unknown\",
  \"ResponseType\": \"code id_token token\",
  \"ResponseMode\": \"form_post\",
  \"Flow\": \"Hybrid\",
  \"RequestedScopes\": \"openid profile authApi\",
  \"State\": \"OpenIdConnect.AuthenticationProperties=4I58lykxVY2o_DR_dipZnuprBNwlLo9odAzf8T7Gqqv1PHrVNdz6i3Y6k240eUbMQ9_2hVXMmrFO9M27XjPjRWqr9BkvCDvINKKLW5k8DUTLLhY9QPomOBkqo3TpuI0BQnOYR5JOBDlHYrKdbMdDTsheqkYn57FyGdyRQi3SYgb81e2epm3irABcWL5oYZxNQkDGMZw2Ne8RvMSAITI4voTj6xyuOOMjdZ08iA\",
  \"Nonce\": \"636322729757330701.YTUwZTFhMGMtYjEyYi00ODFkLWE3ODYtMGY2NDE0ZGY1NzljMmUyZjIzZmEtMTZjYy00YTg0LTljMmMtOGU2NTAwOWIyZjVm\",
  \"Raw\": {
    \"client_id\": \"\",
    \"redirect_uri\": \"https://localhost/YouthReengagement/SelectOrganization\",
    \"response_mode\": \"form_post\",
    \"response_type\": \"code id_token token\",
    \"scope\": \"openid profile authApi\",
    \"state\": \"OpenIdConnect.AuthenticationProperties=4I58lykxVY2o_DR_dipZnuprBNwlLo9odAzf8T7Gqqv1PHrVNdz6i3Y6k240eUbMQ9_2hVXMmrFO9M27XjPjRWqr9BkvCDvINKKLW5k8DUTLLhY9QPomOBkqo3TpuI0BQnOYR5JOBDlHYrKdbMdDTsheqkYn57FyGdyRQi3SYgb81e2epm3irABcWL5oYZxNQkDGMZw2Ne8RvMSAITI4voTj6xyuOOMjdZ08iA\",
    \"nonce\": \"636322729757330701.YTUwZTFhMGMtYjEyYi00ODFkLWE3ODYtMGY2NDE0ZGY1NzljMmUyZjIzZmEtMTZjYy00YTg0LTljMmMtOGU2NTAwOWIyZjVm\"
  }
}"
2017-06-05 08:22:56.179 -07:00 [Information] User is not authenticated. Redirecting to login.
2017-06-05 08:22:56.179 -07:00 [Information] End authorize request
2017-06-05 08:22:56.179 -07:00 [Information] Redirecting to login page
2017-06-05 08:22:56.179 -07:00 [Debug] Protecting message: "{\"ReturnUrl\":\"https://SCRUBBED.ADDRESS/OspiSts/identity/connect/authorize?client_id=&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%2FYouthReengagement%2FSelectOrganization&response_mode=form_post&response_type=code%20id_token%20token&scope=openid%20profile%20authApi&state=OpenIdConnect.AuthenticationProperties%3D4I58lykxVY2o_DR_dipZnuprBNwlLo9odAzf8T7Gqqv1PHrVNdz6i3Y6k240eUbMQ9_2hVXMmrFO9M27XjPjRWqr9BkvCDvINKKLW5k8DUTLLhY9QPomOBkqo3TpuI0BQnOYR5JOBDlHYrKdbMdDTsheqkYn57FyGdyRQi3SYgb81e2epm3irABcWL5oYZxNQkDGMZw2Ne8RvMSAITI4voTj6xyuOOMjdZ08iA&nonce=636322729757330701.YTUwZTFhMGMtYjEyYi00ODFkLWE3ODYtMGY2NDE0ZGY1NzljMmUyZjIzZmEtMTZjYy00YTg0LTljMmMtOGU2NTAwOWIyZjVm\",\"ClientId\":\"\",\"AcrValues\":[],\"Created\":636322729754766756}"
2017-06-05 08:22:56.195 -07:00 [Information] Login page requested
2017-06-05 08:22:56.195 -07:00 [Debug] signin message passed to login: "{
  \"ReturnUrl\": \"https://SCRUBBED.ADDRESS/OspiSts/identity/connect/authorize?client_id=&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%2FYouthReengagement%2FSelectOrganization&response_mode=form_post&response_type=code%20id_token%20token&scope=openid%20profile%20authApi&state=OpenIdConnect.AuthenticationProperties%3D4I58lykxVY2o_DR_dipZnuprBNwlLo9odAzf8T7Gqqv1PHrVNdz6i3Y6k240eUbMQ9_2hVXMmrFO9M27XjPjRWqr9BkvCDvINKKLW5k8DUTLLhY9QPomOBkqo3TpuI0BQnOYR5JOBDlHYrKdbMdDTsheqkYn57FyGdyRQi3SYgb81e2epm3irABcWL5oYZxNQkDGMZw2Ne8RvMSAITI4voTj6xyuOOMjdZ08iA&nonce=636322729757330701.YTUwZTFhMGMtYjEyYi00ODFkLWE3ODYtMGY2NDE0ZGY1NzljMmUyZjIzZmEtMTZjYy00YTg0LTljMmMtOGU2NTAwOWIyZjVm\",
  \"ClientId\": \"\",
  \"IdP\": null,
  \"Tenant\": null,
  \"LoginHint\": null,
  \"DisplayMode\": null,
  \"UiLocales\": null,
  \"AcrValues\": [],
  \"Created\": 636322729754766756
}"
2017-06-05 08:22:56.211 -07:00 [Information] rendering login page
2017-06-05 08:22:59.398 -07:00 [Information] Login page submitted
2017-06-05 08:23:00.320 -07:00 [Information] Login credentials successfully validated by user service
2017-06-05 08:23:00.336 -07:00 [Information] {
  "Category": "Authentication",
  "Name": "Local Login Success",
  "EventType": "Success",
  "Id": 1010,
  "Details": {
    "LoginUserName": "alan.okelly@somewhere.com",
    "SignInId": "ada4d366df0e201295962ce26f00f089",
    "SignInMessage": {
      "ReturnUrl": "https://SCRUBBED.ADDRESS/OspiSts/identity/connect/authorize?client_id=&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%2FYouthReengagement%2FSelectOrganization&response_mode=form_post&response_type=code%20id_token%20token&scope=openid%20profile%20authApi&state=OpenIdConnect.AuthenticationProperties%3D4I58lykxVY2o_DR_dipZnuprBNwlLo9odAzf8T7Gqqv1PHrVNdz6i3Y6k240eUbMQ9_2hVXMmrFO9M27XjPjRWqr9BkvCDvINKKLW5k8DUTLLhY9QPomOBkqo3TpuI0BQnOYR5JOBDlHYrKdbMdDTsheqkYn57FyGdyRQi3SYgb81e2epm3irABcWL5oYZxNQkDGMZw2Ne8RvMSAITI4voTj6xyuOOMjdZ08iA&nonce=636322729757330701.YTUwZTFhMGMtYjEyYi00ODFkLWE3ODYtMGY2NDE0ZGY1NzljMmUyZjIzZmEtMTZjYy00YTg0LTljMmMtOGU2NTAwOWIyZjVm",
      "ClientId": "",
      "AcrValues": [],
      "Created": 636322729754766756
    },
    "PartialLogin": false,
    "SubjectId": "44200",
    "Name": "alan.okelly@somewhere.com"
  },
  "Context": {
    "ActivityId": "585c1064-2973-4781-a5ce-9f6bff44a687",
    "TimeStamp": "2017-06-05T15:23:00.3204717+00:00",
    "ProcessId": 7924,
    "MachineName": "DEV-EDSWEB01",
    "RemoteIpAddress": "10.1.11.83"
  }
}
2017-06-05 08:23:00.336 -07:00 [Information] Calling PostAuthenticateAsync on the user service
2017-06-05 08:23:00.351 -07:00 [Information] issuing primary signin cookie
2017-06-05 08:23:00.351 -07:00 [Information] redirecting to: https://SCRUBBED.ADDRESS/OspiSts/identity/connect/authorize?client_id=&redirect_uri=https:%2F%2Flocalhost%2FYouthReengagement%2FSelectOrganization&response_mode=form_post&response_type=code id_token token&scope=openid profile authApi&state=OpenIdConnect.AuthenticationProperties%3D4I58lykxVY2o_DR_dipZnuprBNwlLo9odAzf8T7Gqqv1PHrVNdz6i3Y6k240eUbMQ9_2hVXMmrFO9M27XjPjRWqr9BkvCDvINKKLW5k8DUTLLhY9QPomOBkqo3TpuI0BQnOYR5JOBDlHYrKdbMdDTsheqkYn57FyGdyRQi3SYgb81e2epm3irABcWL5oYZxNQkDGMZw2Ne8RvMSAITI4voTj6xyuOOMjdZ08iA&nonce=636322729757330701.YTUwZTFhMGMtYjEyYi00ODFkLWE3ODYtMGY2NDE0ZGY1NzljMmUyZjIzZmEtMTZjYy00YTg0LTljMmMtOGU2NTAwOWIyZjVm
2017-06-05 08:23:00.414 -07:00 [Information] Start authorize request
2017-06-05 08:23:00.414 -07:00 [Information] Start authorize request protocol validation
```

^^^^^ It just loops over and over from here

Comment: How does the login process actually function? Is the user literally taken to a different site to login and then redirected back or are modal windows with iframes being utilized?

Comment: Does turning off IE's compatibility mode for intranet sites fix it?

Comment: The login actually leaves the site to log in on another server. When the call returns the Authentication functionality in .NET is supposed to take the cookie that is returned and use that to prove that it's now authenticated. I believe that's the step that's failing in IE, but not Chrome or Firefox.

Comment: Compatibility mode is not currently on for the site. I've tried toggling settings in the emulation section in Developer Tools as well, but to no effect.